# onchange event not firing on first change in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<form class="uk-form-stacked">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="kUI_dropdown_basic_select">Select a user</label>
    <select id="kUI_dropdown_basic_select" class="uk-form-width-medium" onchange="getIPL();">
        <?php  foreach ($response->result->allAcc as $data) { ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $data->Id;?>">   <?php echo $data->Name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>


<script>
function getIPL() {
    var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'kUI_dropdown_basic_select' );
    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
    window.open( 'admin_mailbox.php?Id=' + this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,"_self");
    };
}
</script>
```

Thank you for taking the time for reading my question.
`onchange()` is not working for the first time
second time it works fine

Comment: It likely is working. The `change` event just uses multiple handlers at different times. – The first occurrence of `change` invokes `getIPL()`, which just replaces itself as the handler with a different function. That 2nd function then opens new windows on each subsequent occurrence of the event.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `onchange` from `select` box. And change your JS with this :

```
<script>

    var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'kUI_dropdown_basic_select' );
    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
    window.open( 'admin_mailbox.php?Id=' + this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,"_self");
    };

</script>
```

Comment: There is no onclick event

Comment: Oh yes it's `onchage`. Thanks.

Comment: also suggest to add a default <option value="">Select</option> otherwise ist option selected as default and will not work... maybe..

Comment: @devpro It works if user will change the value of `select` box.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy and simple code below

```
<form class="uk-form-stacked">
   <label class="uk-form-label" for="kUI_dropdown_basic_select">Select a user</label>

   <select id="kUI_dropdown_basic_select" onmousedown="this.value='';" class="uk-form-width-medium" onchange="getIPL(this.value);">
      <option  value="aaa">aaa</option>
      <option  value="bbb">bbb</option>
      <option  value="ccc">ccc</option>
      <option  value="ddd">ddd</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

javascript function

```
function getIPL(value) {
  //var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'kUI_dropdown_basic_select' );
  //urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  window.open( 'admin_mailbox.php?Id=' + value,"_self"); 
  //};
}
```

Comment: this will work `alert(value); ` but not this `urlmenu.onchange = function() {`

Comment: you don't need to use utlmenu.onchange event again...b'coz it's already working for onchange event

Comment: just use :  window.open( 'admin_mailbox.php?Id=' + value,"_self");

Comment: it's so easy, also you can use jquery for same thing

Comment: i have added it in answer

Comment: yes, jquery is perfect for this, but OP didnt add jquery tag, my vote for u bro.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `document.getElementById` for getting element id, than no need to use `onchange()` event in `<select>`

And i also suggest you to add one more option for selection `<option>Select</option>`

**Test Example (change as per your PHP Code):**

```js
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'kUI_dropdown_basic_select' );
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
window.open( 'admin_mailbox.php?Id=' + this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,"_self");     
};
```

```html
<form class="uk-form-stacked">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="kUI_dropdown_basic_select">Select a user</label>
    <select id="kUI_dropdown_basic_select" class="uk-form-width-medium">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="test1">Test1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

You have already defined onchange event of select box here...then why you use onchange again on same element.

### Use following code

```
<form class="uk-form-stacked">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="kUI_dropdown_basic_select">Select a user</label>
    <select id="kUI_dropdown_basic_select" class="uk-form-width-medium">
        <?php  foreach ($response->result->allAcc as $data) { ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $data->Id;?>">   <?php echo $data->Name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#kUI_dropdown_basic_select").change(function(){
        window.open( 'admin_mailbox.php?Id=' + $(this).val() ,"_self");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You've now introduced jquery into the solution, which needlessly complicates the matter. You do not raise any attention to the fact that you've introduced dependencies with this solution, and it would work quite well with vanilla javascript, as noted by @Mr. Engineer's answer.